# Creating parallel polylines with a constant distance

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop

Can ArcMap fill in selected polygon with many parallel polylines with a constant distance between them and with a particular azimuth?

Comment: I describe how to accomplish this here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/53475/8104

Comment: Do you want the parallel polylines to be features (for analysis) or just part of a polygon fill symbol (for display)?